# Shipping methods for different stores

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, multistore, shipping-methods

I have a multi store setup and want to setup separate shipping methods for each store. Need each method to show specifically for each store. The methods crossover to each of my stores, I have gone into the config and have attempted to disable/enable for each store but have been unsuccessful. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean by store - store view - you have to modify the shipping methods. In the **system.xml** of the shipping method(s) (if you are using the standard/core Magento shipping methods the file is - **app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/etc/system.xml**) search for `<active` and change in it `<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>` to `<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>`. Then you can enable/disable the shipping method for each store view in the admin panel configuration.

Comment: Is this tested? Is it a working and stable solution?